# how to append items to the same row or line with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to append items to the same row with ng-repeat, but it seems to add the items on a new line. In the following example I'd like them to be on the same row like:

"John who is 25 years old. Jessie who is 30 years old. Johanna who is 28 years old."

The result is instead:

John who is 25 years old.
 Jessie who is 30 years old.
 Johanna who is 28 years old.

How can I accomplish that?

```
<div ng-init="friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'}
]">


<div ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</div>
```

Stone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friends" style="float:left">
   {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</div>
```

`OR`

```
<span ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</span>
```

By default `DIV` render as `display:block` and `SPAN` as `display:inline`

Comment: Ahh so he was asking about the text being in the same line! I read his question and I couldn't figure out what was his problem! XD +1 for understanding (right I kind of missed the word "row" )

Comment: Ok, you're right. Now it works here too! Using Firefox, it seems to be a bit slow in refreshing its cache or something. Very much thanks! :)

Comment: `<span>` does not render as `inline-block` by default - it's an `inline` element.