# angular ng-repeat and inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have inherited some code which uses horizontal lists in a form:

```html
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Where `<li>` is inline-block. I need to populate those lists with ng-repeat:

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
</ul>
```

To avoid (well-known) gaps between inline-block elements they have to be written either:

```html
<li>...</li><li>
...</li>
```

Or:

```html
<li>...</li><!--
--><li>...</li>
```

But I have no idea how to achieve that with ng-repeat!
Anyone? :)

P.S.: I read [this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). I wonder if there's an elegant "angular specific" solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to append items to the same row or line with ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349943/how-to-append-items-to-the-same-row-or-line-with-ng-repeat)

Comment: Not exactly. The answer there suggest using floats. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: have a look at edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage them by applying css rule:

```
li{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use negative margin, then you can use `float: left;` instead of inline-block.

---

However, this would be costlier. Another solution I think is using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end like below:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">...</li><!--
  <myDir ng-repeat-end>--></myDir>
</ul>
```

May be you need to use `&gt;` instead of `>` and so on.
And with the compile function remove the element so that there would remain just `-->` using element.unwrap()

I'm not sure the above method would work fine as you're requiring. You could try this once in your project and let me inform.

Comment: 1. Negative margins are dependant on the font-size.
2. Using "float:left" would mean rewriting all html/css which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: -4px will work fine if you don't set font-size zero to ul.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to muck around with css options...

```
ul {
   font-size:0;
}


li {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:12pt;
}
```

Comment: Font-size: 0 presumably doesn't render correctly on pre-JellyBean Androids. Haven't checked myself though.